# virtualbox/docker/VMs - Is it possible to use the VM's PHP from the host?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, docker, docker-for-windows

I have a question regarding the VM's with VirtualBox or any other VManagers like Docker/Vagrant.

Is it possible to have my Windows, say "PHP" command to use the executable in the machine?

i.e, if I invoke `php --version` the output should be the PHP version on my Ubuntu machine?

I had been searching online but I think my vocabulary for which terminology to use is lacking.

Regards,

Comment: I believe the basic answer is "No", excluding network accessible scripts (i.e. like PHP scripts that are run on a web server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About VirtualBox: no, you can't run

```
php --version
```

on the host system and get the php version installed on the guest system.

You can download the php scripts from the virtual machine to the host system (via web server or ftp), then run with the command php in the host system.

Alternatively you can run the php command remotely on the virtual machine (but it's not exactly what you asked).